# DragNDrop on item which is loading after starting dragndrop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have problem with dragndrop on android. I have recicleview and when user taps on some item, another list shows above recicleview and item starts dragndrop. After that, items for second listview are loading and showing on screen, and in getview every items set OnDragListener. Problem is, in second listview list items  show after starting dragndrop and OnDragListener doesn't work. But OnDragListener work if items was added before starting DragNDrop. Do anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem. Since I use CustomListView, I created method isOnChild inside of my CustomListView. And when I receive event drop I call this method and check all child. If it find child view, it transmits DragEvent to that child view. If someone know another solution I will glad to read your variants

```
public boolean isOnChild(View v, DragEvent event){
    int count = getChildCount();
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View view = getChildAt(i);
        int left = view.getLeft();
        int right = view.getRight();
        int top = view.getTop();
        int bottom = view.getBottom();
        if(left < x && x < right && bottom > y && y > top){
            view.dispatchDragEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```